# insertar menu con html5 - No puedo dar estilo a iframe

Tags: html, html5, menú

Tengo una consulta. Soy un desastre en diseño web, y me toca hacer una web para un trabajo de la uni, asique aca mi consulta :/

Estoy tratando de hacer un menú que se inserte en todas las páginas. Como los frames están deprecados en html5 (por lo menos eso leí), intento utilizar iframe.

El problema es que aplico estilos al iframe y estos no se aplican. Intento redimensionarlo, hacer que no haga scroll, etc... Nada funciona.

En si lo que necesitaría es insertar el menú de forma limpia, con un width al 100%, y un min-heigth al 15 - 20%. Estoy utilizando iframe, pero si conocen alguna alternativa mejor con html5, bienvenidos.

Aca una captura de como me queda el sitio:
[image: Pagina fallida]

Espero puedan ayudarme. Muchas gracias!

De momento tengo este codigo:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grabarino</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
        <iframe id="frame" src="header.html"></iframe>


    <div>TODO write content</div>2

</body>
```

header.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Header</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <p id="titulo">Grabarino.com</p>
            <p id="subtitulo">Tu tecno, Tu casa</p>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a class="linkMenu" href="www.google.com">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a class="linkMenu" href="www.google.com">Tienda Online</a></li>
            <li><a class="linkMenu" href="www.google.com">Sucursales</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>

</body>
```

style.css

```
#titulo{
    color:red;
}

body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border:none;
}

#frame{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border:2px;
    height: 550px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    border:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #66ccff;
}


.menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu li{
    display: inline;
}

.linkMenu{
    color:black;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Yo veo que sí le puedes dar estilos. He copiado tu código y lo he modificado un poquito, [mira este enlace](https://plnkr.co/edit/WJJg49u40tfegov24zK9?p=preview). Un header por lo general no debe tener un alto definido tan alto, es mejor que el tamaño del header se adapte a su contenido. Para eso puedes jugar con `padding`.

Comment: sisi, ya se que no queda lindo tan alto jaja, era a modo de prueba. Pero no entiendo por que se hace scroll :/
Me gusta lo del padding, me habia olvidado de eso jaja.

Muchas gracias! Quedó muy bonita, sos un idolo :)

Comment: hace scroll porque hay un desbordamiento; es decir, el contenido sobrepasa los `550px` que le diste al `iframe`. Si no quieres scroll, tan solo debes añadir `body { overflow: hidden; }` pero **en los estilos del header** (`header.css`).

Comment: Si es lo que deseas, comentas para pasarla como respuesta ;)

Comment: Si men. Excelente, muchas gracias por la ayuda.
una ultima consulta, mira:
https://plnkr.co/edit/aZaTtvBIfBnqnlucDFIP?p=preview
Me queda un espacio en blanco antes de la imagen, esto es por que el object no agarra heigth auto. Alguna forma de arreglarlo?

Comment: Otra cosa. Los links no funcionan. Es decir, no me envía ni a google ni a ninguna parte. No me va a dar problemas esto despues?
Perdón por tantas consultas juntas, soy un desastre en diseño web y nunca habia utilizado estos metodos de insercion jaja

Comment: disculpa la demora ;) Ya estoy de vuelta y ya respondí todas tus dudas.

Comment: @FacundoCurti Con `php` sería más fácil trabajar incluir parte de la plantilla mediante `include`. Pero al parecer recién estás empezando en el mundo de la programación existe millones de cursos básicos gratuitos online podrías pasar como vista previa así orientarte mucho más. Saludos :)

Comment: No, tengo que hacer la pagina con java web, cosas del profesor... En realidad hace un tiempo sabia mucho más, pero como no seguí diseñando paginas (me gusta la programacion en C, java etc...), me he olvidado de todo jaja. De todas formas, nunca habia echo esto de incluir una pagina en otra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nota: No debes usar `iframes/objects` para incluir plantillas. Usa alguna librería para templating como [Handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/), [Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug), [Nunjucks](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks) o [Marko](https://github.com/marko-js/marko).

---

> aplico estilos al iframe y estos no se aplican. Intento redimensionarlo, hacer que no haga scroll, etc

Es por que los estilos dedicados deben ser indicados **explíctamente** en el `iframe/object`, de lo contrario, no se tomarán en cuenta:

**header.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">
    <header>
            <p id="titulo">Grabarino.com</p>
            <p id="subtitulo">Tu tecno, Tu casa</p>
        <nav>
          <ul class="menu">
              <li><a class="linkMenu" href="//thehackernews.com">Inicio</a></li>
              <li><a class="linkMenu" href="//muylinux.com">Tienda Online</a></li>
              <li><a class="linkMenu" href="//scotch.io">Sucursales</a></li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
    </header>
```

**header.css**

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'segoe ui';
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
}
header > p {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .6rem .5rem ;
}
nav{
    border:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: #66ccff;
    padding: 1rem .6rem;
}

.menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .5rem;
}

.linkMenu{
  border-radius: 25px;
    color:black;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.linkMenu:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Fíjate que al `body` le hemos  dado `overflow: hidden`. Esto hará que no se muestre el scroll.

---

Luego agregas el header en un `object/iframe`:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grabarino</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <object id="frame" data="header.html" 
            onload="resizeObject(this)" 
            onresize="resizeObject(this)">
    </object>

    <h1 id="titulo">Object/IFrame demo</h1>

    <script>
      function resizeObject(object) {
        var header = object.contentDocument.querySelector('header');
        height = header.offsetHeight;
        object.style.height = height + 'px';
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> mira: [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/aZaTtvBIfBnqnlucDFIP?p=preview) Me queda un espacio en blanco antes de la imagen, esto es por que el object no agarra heigth auto

No, no puedes darle `height` auto a un `iframe/object`. Las medidas **por defecto** de un `iframe/object` son **300px x 150px**. Es por eso que te queda esa imagen como *gap*.

Lo que debes hacer es crear una pequeña función que se ejecute *cuando cargue el `iframe/object`* para que adapte el alto en función del contenido:

```
function resizeObject(object) {
  var header = object.contentDocument.querySelector('header');
  height = header.offsetHeight;
  object.style.height = height + 'px';
}
```

> Los links no funcionan. Es decir, no me envía ni a google ni a ninguna parte

Por defecto, los elementos en un iframe **actúan en su mismo documento**, esto incluye los `anchor`. La solución es agregar la etiqueta `<base />` diciéndole que abra los links en el padre mediante `target="parent"`. Si los quieres abrir en otra pestaña cambias *parent* por *_blank*. Tu `header.html` quedaría así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">
      <base target="_parent" />
        <header>
                <p id="titulo">Grabarino.com</p>
                <p id="subtitulo">Tu tecno, Tu casa</p>
            <nav>
              <ul class="menu">
                  <li><a class="linkMenu" href="//thehackernews.com">Inicio</a></li>
                  <li><a class="linkMenu" href="//muylinux.com">Tienda Online</a></li>
                  <li><a class="linkMenu" href="//scotch.io">Sucursales</a></li>
             </ul>
           </nav>
        </header>
```

---

Al final, tu web quedaría [de ésta manera](https://plnkr.co/edit/fzg8iP6zdXnITiR6vMSr?p=preview).